# Mic and Headphones wont work at the same time

Tags: 14.04, microphone

I have an HP laptop with a built-in microphone, but when i plug my earphones the microphone doesn't work. The headphones don't have a mic of their own. I have Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Does your headphones work perfectly? And have you tested your in-build mic in your ubuntu system? Because , there might even be a problem with your mic.

Comment: yes, and everything works fine on it's own, but when plugged in together, the built-in microphone doesn't work...